# MPDF adding a header and footer to large html

Tags: php, mpdf

I have a large html file.
With Mpdf, I output a pdf and it perfectly work but now I want to add header and footer to all pages.

I have only one section define by my html file.

Here mpdf is in landscape mode.

I try this :

```
        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
            'mode' => 'utf-8',
            'orientation' => 'L'
        ]);

        $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<h1>TEST</h1>');
        $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<h1>TEST</h1>');
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $mpdf->Output($namePDF,'F');
```

but nothing shown in pdf file...

Can't figure why

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$mpdf->SetHeader('First section header');
$mpdf->SetFooter('First section footer');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('First section text...');

// Set the new Header before you AddPage
$mpdf->SetHeader('Second section header');
$mpdf->AddPage();

// Set the new Footer after you AddPage
$mpdf->SetFooter('Second section footer');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Second section text...');

$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: But I don't want to add pages I want my header on all page who Mpdf generate I have only one section define by my html file.

Comment: not working too with old SetHeader and SetFooter methods

Comment: Using SetHeader you can set header.